# QgsMapCanvas map rendering issue

Tags: qgis, c++, rendering, qt, qgsmapcanvas

**Background** : *I am making a raster + vector map navigation application using Qt4 and QGIS in C++. Map is loaded inside `QgsMapCanvas`, which is quite slow, mapcanvas is the part of `QGraphicScene`, `QGraphicScene` is a part of `QGraphicsView`*.

According to the documentation `QgsMapCanvas` uses `QGraphicsView`'s paint method for drawing map..

**Issue:** Processing of `QgsMapCanvas` is slow. Due to slow processing of `QgsMapCanvas` map rendering, the graphicview shows blank area for few milliseconds.

## Question

Is there any way to speed up the rendering of `QgsMapCanvas`? Is there any way to re-render only one layer in `QgsMapCanvas`?

```
canvaslayerSet[7].layer()->triggerRepaint();
```

I have tried this. According to some forms it repaints only single layer. But it doesn't work.